# Storage classes: Understanding Static

Tags: c, static, output, storage-class-specifier

I am not able to understand the output of this program-

```
int main()
{
    static int i=5;
    if(--i) {
        main();
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
}
```

The output is 0 0 0 0

My doubt is why wont static be initialized in the first call to main?
The output if I assume static gets initialized in the first call to 5, and then gets shared between calls should be 4 3 2 1

Thanks!

Comment: "*To understand recursion you need to understand recursion ...*"

Comment: "*My doubt is why wont static be initialized in the first call to main*" it will be. Where do you think the `5-1` `0`s come from.

Comment: Try changing the order of calls to `main` and `printf`, check the result and think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `main()` is called recursively 4 times before any `printf()` statement is called. By the time the first `printf()` gets called, `--i` has been called recursively 4 times. Since `i` is static, its value is 0 at that point and that's the value that is printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't choose `i` to be `static`, the program will get stuck in infinite calls to `main()` since in each call, there will be new `i` with value of 5. When `main()` is called again, the `printf()` statement is pushed onto stack and later when `i` becomes 0, all the printfs print the value of i, that is 0.